# Creating a list comprehension to find orthogonal neighbours in 2D list

Tags: python, list

How would I go about finding all neighbours of a cell in a 2D list in Python using a list comprehension? I can find all adjacent including diagonal, but I don't want to include the diagonal.

For example, if I have a 2D list as such

```
2   3   5
1   6   None
2   4   8
```

and my current cell is six at grid[1][1], how do I create a list comprehension of neighbours of the grid cell [1][1] if those cells are != None (ie, the values 1,3 and 4, but I need the cell references, not the numbers).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about simply, given that:

- MAXx and MAXy are maximum cells dimensions)
- a,b are coordinates of your cell
- X is your cells

then your list comprehension is

```
[(i,j) for i,j in ((a-1,b), (a+1,b), (a,b-1), (a,b+1)) if 0<=i<MAXX and 0<=j<MAXy and X[i][j] is not None ]
```

Comment: Yes, it does not take them. It is assumed to be substituted by the maximum values (that is why I wrote "given MAXx and MAXy **are** maximum cells dimensions).

Comment: I wraped it in the function only for easier separation of arguments (so it is clear which parts are which) that are given, OP asked for list comprehension solution, not the function or any more complex structure. But you are right,that it may confuse someone, I removes the function structure

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was after. I need it to solve another dynamic programming problem to do with traversing over a matrix that deletes the half that you don't look at, in order to find the maximum number of items that could be "grabbed". Hard to explain, part of a math game thing. I had the logic behind it down, but got stumped on this part.